# Failed to load https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, axios, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to get a token using the Outlook REST API after I got the code from this url `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`

I used a `POST` request with axios but the issue is I got this error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

My  Axios post is this:

```js
return Axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*', Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
    },
    data: {
        'client_id': 'xxxxxx',
        'scope': 'calendars.readwrite',
        'code': encodeURIComponent('000000000'),
        'redirect_uri': encodeURIComponent('http://localhost:3000/storeprofile/xxxxxxxxx/outlook-scheduler'),
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'client_secret': encodeURIComponent('xxxxxxxxxx')
    };,
    responseType: 'json'
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log('token response: ', response);
    });
```

I get a `200` status but can't see the token I am supposed to get in the response. The response should be a `json` but still nothing.

Can someone please guide me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47185296/1658906. **Do not use authorization code flow from front-end JavaScript!** Your client secret is now public.

Comment: Hi @paolacl were you able to resolve this out ?

Comment: you just need to change the app type from WEB to SPA. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59844516/how-to-enable-cors-in-an-azure-app-registration-when-used-in-an-oauth-authorizat

Answer (score 0):

When you register your app, you must setup the `Redirect URI/URL`, usually this url will be added to the [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) header.

doc : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview#how-do-i-get-my-app-talking-to-azure-ad-and-microsoft-graph

Comment: thanks for your comment, I added the redirect uri/url when I created the app on Outlook but still nothing yet.