# Reactjs || How to Connect with Azure Blob Storage || Getting CORS Error

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am new to Azure and reactjs, my objective is to remove the SAS token-based connection for Azure blob storage with managed identity because the SAS token tends to expire after some time which cannot be a recommended solution for going into the production environment.
Background:
In C# to connect with the database using managed identity I am using the following code, and it works perfectly

```js
 static SqlConnection getConString()
 {
    var ConnectionString = "Server details here (server name,and database name)";
    var sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
    var token = credential.GetToken(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext
                    (
    new[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" }));
    sqlconnection.AccessToken = token.Token;
    return sqlconnection;
 }
```

I was looking for a similar method for reactjs but I came to know that there is no such library that can be called directly and we can establish a connection with Azure blob storage, after doing a lot of research I concluded that if we want to connect with azure blob storage via managed identity we need to use "Enterprise Application Registration", I am following below link for doing the same.

https://dev.to/425show/connecting-to-azure-blob-storage-from-react-using-azure-identity-16l0
I have app registration with the following:

[image]

But when I am running the code, I am getting a CORS error, saying that Application Registration is not allowed to generate tokens, I did research and edited the manifest file of Azure app registration and enabled below are a few details of the app registration manifest

```js
"oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": true,     "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,    "oauth2Permissions": [],    "oauth2RequirePostResponse": true,
        "optionalClaims": null,
            "acceptMappedClaims": null,     "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": null,     "addIns": [],   "allowPublicClient": null,  "appRoles": [],
        "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": true
```

Please let me know what I am missing, I am about to give up on this. Any other alternatives will also work like 1- Auto Renewal of SAS tokens 2- Generating SAS token Dynamically etc.

I am connecting with the Azure Blob Storage account from Reactjs via Managed Identity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable CORS in an Azure App Registration when used in an OAuth Authorization Flow with PKCE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59844516/how-to-enable-cors-in-an-azure-app-registration-when-used-in-an-oauth-authorizat)

Comment: @akseli I have tried the above answer mentioned in chat with following "replyUrlsWithType": [
  {
   "url": "http://localhost:3000/Sas",
   "type": "Spa"
  }
 ], please let me know if I tried in a wrong way, it didn't work for me

Comment: Make sure that you're including `http://` or `https://` in your URLs, both in Azure Portal and any other places you're configuring the ReplyUrls. Also, check this out: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-tutorial/blob/main/2-Authorization-I/2-call-arm/README.md